# What is the time complexity of recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a recursive function. And i’m looking for what is the time complexity ?
Here is the function

```
 public static int f7(int N){
         if (N==1) return 0;
         return 1 + f7(N/2);
   }
```

Comment: If N is 10, it will 3 times recursive call. Am i right?

Comment: Seem it will be O(log(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we come up with a recurrence for this function:

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
```

This is a recurrence that we can plug into the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), which will give us Θ(log n) as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that when `N=1`, the call takes `a` time units, and when `N` is a power of 2, it takes `b` time units, *not counting the recursive call*.

Then

```
T(1) = a
T(2^n) = T(2^(n-1)) + b.
```

This can be seen as an ordinary linear recurrence

```
S(0) = a
S(n) = S(n-1) + b = S(n-2) + 2b = … = S(0) + nb = a + nb,
```

or

```
T(N) = a + Lg(N) b
```

where `Lg` denotes the base-2 logarithm.

When `N` is not a power of 2, the time is the same as for the nearest inferior power of 2.

The exact formula for all `N` is

```
T(N) = a + [Lg(N)] b.
```

Brackets denote the floor function.